# docker stack: Redis not working on worker node

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I just completed the docker documentation and created two instances on aws (http://13.127.150.218, http://13.235.134.73). The first one is manager and the second one is the worker. Following is the composed file I used to deploy

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: username/repo:tag
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/data:/data"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Here the redis service has the constraint that restricts it to run only on manager node. Now my question is how the web service on worker instance is supposed to use the redis service.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the hostname parameter in all container, so you can use this value to access services from worker or to access from worker the services on manager.

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: username/repo:tag
    hostname: "web"
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    hostname: "visualizer"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    hostname: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/data:/data"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

In addictional if you use the portainer instead of visualizer you can control you SWARM stack with more options:

https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer

BR,

Carlos

Comment: I added hostnames to my services and deployed the stack again. But it didn't help to resolve the issue. you can check here http://13.235.134.73/

Comment: I am using aws and I have opened the TCP port 6379 on manager node.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the stack file as per the below example -
[image]

Regardless of where it is placed manager|worker all the services in the stack file being on the same network can use the embedded DNS functionality which helps to resolve each service by the service name defined.
In this case the service `web` makes use of service `redis` by its service name.

Here is an example of the ping command able to resolve the service `web` from within the container associated with the redis service -
[image]

Read more about the [Swarm Native Service Discovery](https://success.docker.com/article/networking#swarmnativeservicediscovery) to understand this.

Comment: This is How I am connecting to redis.
`redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)`

Comment: I have 2 servers one is manager and the other is worker. My question is "can service from manger (or worker) access the service on worker (or manager).